# SPA using c# and angular js code in SharePoint provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom, adfs, angularjs

We have built an app using provider hosted SharePoint app model with angularjs. Now we are planning to use the app on a SharePoint site which is integrated to ADFS. When I google on how to use ADFS with apps mostly articles guide towards using tokenhelper class. My question is as the app has been already built and uses sprequestor.js , how should I incorporate token helper.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned app is built using REST and angular js , key is to modify web.config where we have to define ADFS provider and URN related so that app gets authenticated independently as stated in below article. Please ping me if you need any help on the configuration. 
https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/saml-support-for-sharepoint-hosted-apps-with-adfs-3-0/